# Print a number (or string) in specific number max characters

Tags: c#, c, string

Is there an equivalent of C's
`printf("%8d", n)` in C# for numbers and strings?

So can I somehow allocate a specific size where a string or a number
will be printed and if the string or number is smaller, extra spaces will
be added instead?

Comment: IIRC, something like `Console.Write("{1:8}", n);`. Or maybe `{1,8}`. I haven't really used the formatting :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

The format of a format specifier is

```
{ index[,alignment][ :formatString] }
```

We can plug 0 for the index and 8 for the alignment, causing it to be aligned to 8 characters.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("\"" + string.Format("{0,8}", 1234) + "\"");
Console.WriteLine("\"" + string.Format("{0,15}", 7) + "\"");
```

Which gives us:

```
"    1234"
"              7"
```

We can also specify a negative value for the alignment, which will left align the string, rather that right align like before.

```
string.Format("{0,-10}", 72);
```

Which outputs

```
"72        "
```

Hopefully that clears it up for you :)

EDIT:

As chris points out, the Console.WriteLine function itself takes a format string, removing the necessity to call string.Format() explicitly. That means you can align strings like so.

```
Console.WriteLine("\"{0,8}\"", 1234);
```

Formatting our string and writing it to the console, all in a single statement.

Comment: When your answer is based off of a link, add a summary of the link. Sometimes, links go dead, and if that happens, there's nothing left. The immediate answer should be readily visible.

Comment: I'll edit my answer now, sorry, I'm new here if you couldn't tell :)

Comment: Ah, I just got to getting it working myself (dumb online compiler didn't put in the spaces). One note is that the `Format()` call is unnecessary. `"\"{0,8}\"", 1234` is fine.